# $.getJson fails although the weatherapp link works correctly

Tags: javascript, json, frontend

I'm doing the project in https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/show-the-local-weather

My full project is here if you need: https://codepen.io/tugrulz/pen/beEmJb?editors=0010

```
function fetchWeather() {

  var ap = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?";
  var key = "&appid=061f24cf3cde2f60644a8240302983f2";
  var lat = "35";
  var lon = "139";
  var api = ap + "lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + key;

  $(".location").html(api);

$.getJSON(api, function(data) {
      alert("sa");
      $(".location").html("oldu mu?");
    })
   .done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function(error) {
    alert( error );

  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });
}
```

This prints: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=061f24cf3cde2f60644a8240302983f2

The problem is, the link I print works in chrome correctly but the getJSON does not work. Its fail function works.

What should I do?
And any idea how do I print the error message? print(error); does not help. neither a try and catch statement involving getJson.

Comment: Are you sure you call `fetchWeather()`. Look at this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aZNEgz). It is basically your code and I write the response name into a div. So it works.

Comment: Yes I do, but it's in ready function and I use bootstrap but none of those made a difference when I changed them. interesting. I will use yours as a template then but I'm still curious what is the difference between the projects.

Comment: I really don't know whats the difference between our 2 versions is. I updated my pen to include the `fetchWeather()` call in the `$(document).ready()` and it still works.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your codepen project and in my console I got the error

```
The page at 'https://codepen.io/tugrulz/pen/beEmJb?editors=0011' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=061f24cf3cde2f60644a8240302983f2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Codepen is blocking the api because it is not an `https` address. It's not printing an error because the request is never even getting sent to the weather service.